# Закрытие доступа к страницам php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть страницы index.php, catalog.php и item.php . Как закрыть к ним доступ не авторизированному пользователю на сайте? (без использования javascript)

Что бы пользователя, который не авторизовался, перекидывало на страницу авторизации или на страницу с ошибкой. 

Заранее спасибо!

(Если будет не трудно, опишите пожалуйста конкретно метод)

Comment: `<?php if(!isAuth()) {header('/login.php');} else {.....}?>` в общем случае как то так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После успешной авторизации, записывайте, например, ID пользователя в сессию:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $assoc['id'];
```

На страницах проверяйте существование сессии

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: /login");
    exit;
}
```

После выхода с учетной записи, удаляйте сессию

```
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Записывая ID в сессию, Вы сможете идентифицировать пользователя на любой странице.

Comment: Спасибо что указали хороший пример и дали направление куда копать!